# Servlet program showing HTTP STATUS 404

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

I have written this code for servlet

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;


public class Httpservlet1  extends HttpServlet 
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String color = request.getParameter("color");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<B>The selected color is: ");
        pw.println(color);
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

i have compiled it and its corresponding html file action attribute value is

```
action="http://localhost:8765/HS/HTTPSERVLET">
```

and 
web.xml contains

servlet-name four
servlet-class  Httpservlet1

servlet-name  four
url-pattern    /HTTPSERVLET in xml code format still its showing error message on running it

[image]

Comment: Is your application named `HS.war` or is it placed in `/webapps/HS` directory?

Comment: it is placed in /webapps/HS directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your web.xml is not properly formed.
It works OK for me.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>four</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Httpservlet1</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>four</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HTTPSERVLET</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```